# DbSet<TEntity>.Local.Any() performance issue when upgraging EF Core from 2.2.6 to 3.1.3

Tags: c#, performance, .net-core, entity-framework-core, dbset

There is a method which is responsible for returning a single GitCommit object based on its hash from our git commit cache database table. We use **Entity Framework Core**, and when I've **upgraded the nuget packages from 2.2.6 to 3.1.3** I've realized a strange performance issue. Beginning with the second call of the method with 2.2.6 the condition **_dbContext.GitCommitCache.Local.Any()** took **0-1ms** to perform, on 3.1.3 is takes usually around **150-220ms**. I'm running this method around 9 to 10 thousand times and its a huge performance bottleneck. Is there anything related that's changed under the hood? Does this have any trivial solutions to keep the original performance?

```
    public async Task<GitCommit> GetCommitAsync(string hash)
    {
        try
        {
            await _semaphore.WaitAsync();
            if (!_dbContext.GitCommitCache.Local.Any())
            {
                await _dbContext.GitCommitCache.LoadAsync();
            }
            var cacheEntry = await _dbContext.GitCommitCache.FindAsync(hash);

            if (cacheEntry != null)
            {
                return cacheEntry;
            }

            var commit = await GetCommitDataAsync(hash);

            try
            {
                _dbContext.GitCommitCache.Add(commit);
                await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateException)
            {
                _dbContext.Entry(commit).State = EntityState.Detached;
            }

            return commit;
        }
        finally
        {
            _semaphore.Release();
        }
    }
```

Comment: it's hard to believe that your query was taking 0-1 ms to be executed. the following quote is taken from MSDN book "It can take ~100ms to open a new connection to a database." I'm not saying that there is no reason/answer to your question, but i am just showing you this information that i read about a few days ago from a MSDN book.

Comment: As I mentioned the 0-1ms response time is resulted after the second run, first run is obviously slow.

Comment: @CataHotea There's no db connection involved in calling `Local`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [issue #14001](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/14001), i.e. EF core 3.0.0, it was added that `DetectChanges` is called when accessing `Local`:

```cs
public override LocalView<TEntity> Local
{
    get
    {
        CheckKey();

        if (_context.ChangeTracker.AutoDetectChangesEnabled)
        {
            _context.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();
        }

        return _localView ??= new LocalView<TEntity>(this);
    }
}
```

`DetectChanges` is a complex and therefore relatively slow method. Fortunately, as you see, if you disable `AutoDetectChangesEnabled` temporarily, just for calling `Local`, you will be up to speed again.

I think it's safe do that, assuming that there are no undetected changes in `_dbContext` when you enter the method.